# Ignoring escape characters in a char buffer received through HTTP GET C++

Tags: c++, string, sockets, char, escaping

I'm sending a request to get an image from a webpage.
I'm using C++ with winsocket and tcp http get request.
I receive all the info in my char buffer but when I stream it to a file or string it's very short because there are string terminators in it.
What's the best/most efficient way to deal with the escape characters?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
    ofstream out("temp.jpg");

```
    //m_Received.reserve(STRINGBUFFERSIZE);
    char rBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];

    int readSize = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;

    do
    {
        PRINT("Reset buffer");
        ZeroMemory(rBuffer, sizeof(rBuffer));

        PRINT("Receiving...");
        readSize = recv(socket, rBuffer, sizeof(rBuffer), 0);

        PRINT("Received " << readSize << " bytes...");
        if (readSize > 0)
        {
            totalSize += readSize;
            //m_Received.append(rBuffer);

            for (int i = 0; i < readSize; ++i)
            {
                out << rBuffer[i];
            }

            if (readSize < BUFFERSIZE)
            {
                PRINT("Stopping receiving...");
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (readSize == -1)            
            throw SocketError("ErrorReceiving", readSize);

    } while (readSize > 0);
```

Even when putting each character in individually I get a small difference with the original image which leads to corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I fixed it by simply writing the char buffer binary to my file. Should have thought of this earlier.